# Why would my template not show when channel entry limit parameter is set higher than 1 with Playa parent tag is within?

Tags: channel-entries, playa

I have two channels; A and B.
Channel B has a Playa field that relates that entry to entries from Channel A.

In my template, I am wanting to show all the entries from Channel A and display the title of entries from Channel B via the Playa Parent tag.

Here is my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channelA" limit="1000"} 
<article id="{url_title}" class="info"> 
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <ul>
        {exp:playa:parents channel="channelB"}
        <li><a href="{path='/site/view/{url_title}'}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:playa:parents}
    </ul>
</article>    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If the channel entry limit is set to anything higher than 1, the template is a white screen.  But if the limit is set to "1" it works for the most recent entry only.

If i remove the Playa code, the template shows as it should.
Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if the limit is 2 or 5? 1000 is a lot of entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into PHP’s memory limit. You can read about how to increase that here: http://www.hostucan.com/webmaster-tutorials/increase-php-memory-limit

Comment: That is exactly the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case... have you tried `dynamic="no"` in your outer entries tag?

Comment: I would also suggest (though you may have removed them just for simplicity's sake here) adding params to both tag pairs for disable= for example.

Comment: Jim - yep dynamic="no" was my first go to, no dice.
Jean - disable was in place, no dice either.